# How can JavaScript use document.querySelectorAll get all rows of table in several pages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table, frontend

I have a html:

```
<table id="emp-table">
    <thead>
        <th col-index = 1>Employee ID</th>
        <th col-index = 2>Gender</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>101</td>
            <td>M</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>102</td>
            <td>M</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>103</td>
            <td>F</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

the page code is:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
      <li><a href="?page=1">1</a></li>
      <li><a  href="?page=2">2</a></li>
      <li><a  href="?page=2">Next</a></li>
      <li><a  href="?page=5">Last »</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Using the following js code I can only get rows in one of the pages each time, but not able to get all rows for both pages at the same time :

```
const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#emp-table > tbody > tr")
```

Any friend can help ,I want to get all rows in all the pages.

Comment: JavaScript can only access the contents of the current page.

Comment: If you want to use javascript to access all rows on all pages, you can always display ALL of the content on one page. Then use javascript to handle the pagination so the user stays on the same page.

Comment: @imvain2 can you show me how to display all of the content on one page ?

Comment: @William, there are two parts to that. The data generation and the front end. Do you know how to pull back all of the data using your back end? That is the most important part.

Comment: The question doesn't provided enough information to suggest a solution. How is the table generated and how does the pagination work?